# What is the distinction between Phong Shading/Interpolation and the Phong Illumination Model?

Tags: opengl, graphics, lighting

My class notes have made it clear that these two are not the same. I understand that the Phong Illumination Model is ambiant+diffuse+specular, but where does Phong Shading come into play when it comes to lighting? What about BRDFs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An illumination model (or reflectance model) tells you for a given surface point, light, and viewer, the amount of light that is reflected towards the viewer. The Phong illumination model does this with the three light components you described and is a special case of a BRDF (only the diffuse and specular part; the ambient part cannot be modeled with a standard BRDF). The illumination model is completely continuous and only defined in physical space (although they need not adhere to a physical illumination model).

A shading model is a strategy to produce an image based on the shape and and illumination model. More specifically, it defines where to evaluate the illumination model and what to do with the result. The Phong shading model evaluates the illumination model at every pixel and uses the result directly as the pixel color. Other shading models evaluate the illumination model only at vertices and blend the colors (Gouraud) or once per face (flat).

Comment: @NicoShertler Thanks for the answer. So, just to be clear: the lighting in this tutorial is using the Phong Illumination Model and a flat shading model? https://learnopengl.com/Lighting/Basic-Lighting

Comment: After looking at the page again, I see that it couldn't possibly be using flat shading, as the final picture has a side that is not flatly shaded. But it that case, what shading model is it using?

Comment: Looks like both Phong shading and Phong illumination.

Comment: How could you tell?

Comment: We don't see the wireframe of the model, so there is no accurate way to tell. But assuming that the model only contains vertices at the cube corners, we can see that the color is neither constant in a face nor a linear interpolation, hence Phong shading is the most likely shading model. For the illumination, well, that is what the code is doing.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I just don't see, based on the shaders (vertex: https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/2.lighting/2.2.basic_lighting_specular/2.2.basic_lighting.vs), (fragment: https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/2.lighting/2.2.basic_lighting_specular/2.2.basic_lighting.fs) how this is considered phong shading. Is it specifically *because* these calculations are done in the fragment shader that the shading is considered per-pixel and therefore Phong Shading? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes. If your fragment shader evaluates the illumination model, you have per-pixel lighting and therefore Phong shading. For Gouraud shading, the vertex shader does the work.

Comment: Interesting. How would one implement the phong illumination model with flat shading?

Comment: You still evaluate it in the vertex shader, but you specify the output attribute with the `flat` qualifier, e.g., `flat out vec4 color`. This will pass the non-interpolated color to the fragment shader.

Answer (score 1):

Phong Shading is a method used to calculate the shading on an object.
To calculate the shading of a point on an object, the *normals of the vertices* are interpolated.
In comparison, flat shading only uses the normal of the polygon. Phong shading will result in smoother, more curved edges while at the same time not requiring a lot of polygons.

Also see [this article](https://opengl-notes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/lighting/shading.html) and especially the picture.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am more confused with the way the Phong Illumination Model fits in with Phong Shading. If my understading of Nico's answer is correct, the shading model dictates how we apply the illumination model (once per triangle, per vertex, or per fragment). In that case, what shading model is being used in this tutorial? https://learnopengl.com/Lighting/Basic-Lighting Thanks.